# How to open Excel with VBA Macros without warning

Tags: excel, vba

I created Excel using VBA macros but for opening this .xls sheet it is asking permission like enable content before opening.

Please check the screen shot where I marked with red color.

[image]

I want avoid that warning from code or back end, So please suggest something how to avoid it.

Comment: You can't; this operating as expected to prevent code from executing without users consent. You can mark the document as trusted & educate users to click the button.

Comment: Or you can digitally sign your VBA codes with a certificate and trust this certificate in Windows. See [Microsoft support: Digitally sign a macro project](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-a-macro-project-6e5de679-01d4-4387-85e0-92e3e9a49483).

Answer (score 1):

One can go to Excel Options -> Trust Center on the Trust Center button -> under External Content choose the Enable All Data Connections option.
[image]

In Excel go to Options -> Trust Center -> Protected View and disable all three options
[image]

Last option is to enable all macro content[image]

Comment: That's right. Someone had the problem that it still didnt work after disabling, then just add the folder with your file to trusted locations. Didnt want to post another answer.